# Adding variables to the shell script that have to run on remote_host

Tags: ansible

I've got a task to run a shell script on remote host using ansible. I have created a role which copy, run and delete the shell script on remote host. When I run the main playbook with this role in it, the job runs as expected. But I have some credentials in the script and I've to do this task using variables in the place of credentials in shellscript. How can I direct ansible to run the shellscript on the remote node with variables from localhost.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

since you have not paste your scripts here,ill explain with an example.

```
command: "sh /path/to/shellscript.sh {{variable1}} {{variable2}}
```

You can pass variable from play as above.

```
ansible-playbook myplay.yml -e variable1=foo -e variable2=bar
```

You can run play-book as above.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Here variable values are passed through arguments(extra variables i believe). What if the credentials in the shellscript should be called from ansible vault?

Comment: Yes using vault is possible. You can also use ansible encrypt. This will encrypt the variable using an algorithm. You can define the encrypted value inside the playbook define as vars before tasks or pass that as extra vars during the execution
If you want to use ansible vaults.Give it a try. If you are facing any issue update the question.

Comment: you can refer https://medium.com/devops-process-and-tools/manage-secrets-with-ansible-vault-d0528b7a99f4